# I have two SQL queries. I need to join them into a single SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two sql queries which I need to combine into a single one. When I'm trying to combine these 2 queries into a single one, I'm not getting the right result. Someone please help in combining these 2 queries into a single query.

First SQL Query:

```
SELECT distinct order_no,status,status_cd,
case when order_qty - fulfilled_qty > 0 then 'inventory-unavailable' END
from t1 a, t2 b
where 
a.inventory_stockout='TRUE'
AND a.flag_column='TRUE' 
and status in '(fulfilled','pending')
GROUP BY order_no,status,status_cd;
```

Second SQL Query:

```
SELECT distinct order_no,status,status_cd,
case when order_qty - fulfilled_qty > 0 then 'inventory-unavailable' END
from t1 a, t2 b
where 
a.inventory_stockout='TRUE'
AND a.flag_column='TRUE' 
and a.subscription_enabled='TRUE'
GROUP BY order_no,status,status_cd;
```

Comment: MySQL I suppose...?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: Your queries are invalid in several ways, and do probably not produce the result you think they are doing. That's your major problem!

Answer (score 1):

If both of them - separately - return result you want (I doubt it; you're using cross-join between `t1` and `t2`), then a simple option is to `union` them (remove `distinct`, remove `group by` (doesn't make sense anyway as you aren't aggregating anything, but `distinct` does the job) as `union` replaces both of them in this case):

```
SELECT order_no,
       status,
       status_cd,
       CASE
          WHEN order_qty - fulfilled_qty > 0 THEN 'inventory-unavailable'
       END
  FROM t1 a, t2 b
 WHERE     a.inventory_stockout = 'TRUE'
       AND a.flag_column = 'TRUE'
       AND status IN ('fulfilled', 'pending')
UNION
SELECT order_no,
       status,
       status_cd,
       CASE
          WHEN order_qty - fulfilled_qty > 0 THEN 'inventory-unavailable'
       END
  FROM t1 a, t2 b
 WHERE     a.inventory_stockout = 'TRUE'
       AND a.flag_column = 'TRUE'
       AND a.subscription_enabled = 'TRUE';
```

Comment: Or do one `SELECT DISTINCT`, with `... AND (status IN ('fulfilled', 'pending') OR a.subscription_enabled = 'TRUE');`

Comment: If the above answers(s) resolved your issue then kingly accept one of them. This helps  future questioners with similar issue and removes the question from the unanswered queue. Please do not leave successfully answered questions as unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

One question:  I see t1 and t2 and synonyms but don't see the join condition or the key logic that joins t1 and t2 together.  Do you know what the PK/FK relationship is between those tables?

Suggestion: You're hitting the same table in both with most of the same conditions and same case logic.  So, if you combined into a single query, you'd make one pass through the tables which would probably be faster than a UNION.  If you add some () to the AND logic, would enable you to do this.  Can you try this style and see if it works?

-- Combined Code Mockup

```
SELECT distinct order_no,status,status_cd,
  CASE when order_qty - fulfilled_qty > 0 then 'inventory-unavailable' END
  FROM t1 a, t2 b
 WHERE t1.PK = t2.FK (Add...)
   AND a.inventory_stockout='TRUE'
   AND a.flag_column='TRUE' 
   AND (status in '(fulfilled','pending' OR (AND a.flag_column='TRUE' 
        AND a.subscription_enabled='TRUE'))
GROUP BY order_no,status,status_cd;
```

Answer (score 1):

even if you know which table `order_qty` came from given you have aliased your two tables `a` & `b` it best to always use the alias, to same what you mean.

also having things that look like booleans `inventory_stockout` & `flag_column` is bad performance if they truely are string encoded booleans.

Also DISTINCT is a GROUP BY, but given you have DISTINCT you don't need declare the GROUP BY stage, as all the variables are considered. Also as a Snowflake note,  this_should_have_a_name is not named in the GROUP BY but it also does not need to be as it is a derivative value from the set of things in the GROUP BY.

I assume you are want the set of the results joined, together, you can [UNION](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/operators-query.html#union-all) them like littlefoot has noted, but this will run a distinct across the two, which is I assume what you would want. Where-as if you know there are zero duplicates in the two result sets, then `UNION ALL` tells the DB to just concatenate the results together, which is much faster.

The next thing you can do is a CTE and sub select the common parts into one block, and then UNION the sub-results like:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        order_no, 
        status,
        status_cd,
        IFF( order_qty - fulfilled_qty > 0, 'inventory-unavailable', NULL) AS this_should_have_a_name,
        a.subscription_enabled
    FROM t1 AS a, t2 AS b
    WHERE a.inventory_stockout = 'TRUE'
        AND a.flag_column = 'TRUE' 
)
SELECT order_no, status, status_cd, this_should_have_a_name
FROM cte
WHERE status in '(fulfilled','pending')

UNION 

SELECT order_no, status, status_cd, this_should_have_a_name
FROM cte
WHERE subscription_enabled='TRUE'
;
```

now we see it written like that, we can just put a OR in there with the CTE

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        order_no, 
        status,
        status_cd,
        IFF( order_qty - fulfilled_qty > 0, 'inventory-unavailable', NULL) AS this_should_have_a_name,
        a.subscription_enabled
    FROM t1 AS a, t2 AS b
    WHERE a.inventory_stockout = 'TRUE'
        AND a.flag_column = 'TRUE' 
)
SELECT order_no, status, status_cd, this_should_have_a_name
FROM cte
WHERE ( status in '(fulfilled','pending')
    OR  subscription_enabled='TRUE' )
;
```

or without the CTE

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        order_no, 
        status,
        status_cd,
        IFF( order_qty - fulfilled_qty > 0, 'inventory-unavailable', NULL) AS this_should_have_a_name
    FROM t1 AS a, t2 AS b
    WHERE a.inventory_stockout = 'TRUE'
        AND a.flag_column = 'TRUE' 
        AND ( status in '(fulfilled','pending') 
            OR a.subscription_enabled='TRUE' )
;
```

OR's can be slower, and now the logic is merged you the logic needed for the UNION ALL can be seen as

```
SELECT order_no, status, status_cd, this_should_have_a_name
FROM cte
WHERE status in '(fulfilled','pending')
    AND subscription_enabled != 'TRUE'

UNION ALL 

SELECT order_no, status, status_cd, this_should_have_a_name
FROM cte
WHERE subscription_enabled = 'TRUE'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :)